# How to set CPU load on a Red Hat Linux box?

Tags: linux, load, redhat, cpu-cycles

I have a [RHEL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) box that I need to put under a moderate and variable amount of CPU load (50%-75%).

What is the best way to go about this? Is there a program that can do this that I am not aware of? I am happy to write some C code to make this happen, I just don't know what system calls will help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is exactly what you need (internet archive link):
[https://web.archive.org/web/20120512025754/http://weather.ou.edu/~apw/projects/stress/stress-1.0.4.tar.gz](https://web.archive.org/web/20120512025754/http://weather.ou.edu/%7Eapw/projects/stress/stress-1.0.4.tar.gz)

From the homepage:
"stress is a simple workload generator for POSIX systems. It imposes a configurable amount of CPU, memory, I/O, and disk stress on the system. It is written in C, and is free software licensed under the GPL."

Comment: Above link is not working. Found it here: http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/

Comment: Both links aren't working. Here's the internet archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20120512025754/http://weather.ou.edu/~apw/projects/stress/stress-1.0.4.tar.gz

Answer (score 2):

Find a simple prime number search program that has source code.  Modify the source code to add a nanosleep call to the main loop with whichever delay gives you the desired CPU load.

Answer (score 1):

One common way to get some load on a system is to compile a large software package over and over again.  Something like the Linux kernel.

Get a copy of the source code, extract the tar.bz2, go into the top level source directory, copy your kernel config from /boot to .config or zcat /proc/config.gz > .config, the do make oldconfig, then while true; do make clean && make bzImage; done

If you have an SMP system, then make -j bzImage is fun, it will spawn make tasks in parallel.

One problem with this is adjusting the CPU load.  It will be a maximum CPU load except for when waiting on disk I/O.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends what you're trying to test.  If you're just testing CPU load, simple scripts to eat empty CPU cycles will work fine.  I personally had to test the performance of a RAID array recently and I relied on Bonnie++ and IOZone.  IOZone will put a decent load on the box, particularly if you set the file size higher than the RAM.

You may also be interested in [this Article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-stress/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly do this using a Bash script.  Use " ps -o pcpu  | grep -v CPU" to get the CPU Usage of all the processes. Add all those values together to get the current usage.  Then have a busy while loop that basically keeps on checking those values, figuring out the current CPU usage, and waiting a calculated amount of time to keep the processor at a certain threshhold.  More detail is need, but hopefully this will give you a good starting point.

Take a look at this [CPU Monitor](http://bashcurescancer.com/media/scripts/monitorCpuUsage.sh.txt) script I found and try to get some other ideas on how you can accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Lookbusy enables set value of CPU load. 
[Project site](http://devin.com/lookbusy/)

```
lookbusy -c util[-high_util], --cpu-util util[-high_util]

i.e. 60% load
lookbusy -c 60
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use some load-generating tool to accomplish this, or run a script to take all the CPU cycles and then use [nice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_%28Unix%29) and `renice` on the process to vary the percentage of cycles that the process gets.

Here is a sample bash script that will occupy all the free CPU cycles:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true ; do
true
done
```

Comment: Or straight from a terminal you could type:
while true; do true; done

Comment: This will load a CPU to 100% CPU but nice and renice won't allow to tune this load, only to weight it with competing processes, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "nice" command.

a) Highest priority:
$ nice -n -20 my_command

or

b) Lowest priority:
$ nice -n 20 my_command

Answer (score 0):

A Simple script to load & hammer the CPU using awk. The script does mathematical calculations and thus CPU load peaks up on higher values passwd to loadserver.sh .

checkout the script @ http://unixfoo.blogspot.com/2008/11/linux-cpu-hammer-script.html

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what your goal is here. I believe glxgears will use 100% CPU.

So find any process that you know will max out the CPU to 100%.

If you have four CPU cores(0 1 2 3), you could use "taskset" to bind this process to say CPUs 0 and 1. That should load your box 50%. To load it 75% bind the process to 0 1 2 CPUs.

Disclaimer: Haven't tested this. Please let us know your results. Even if this works, I'm not sure what you will achieve out of this?